# How make a List of ArrayList in Java?

Tags: list, arraylist

I'm trying to make a list of lists, but I noticed that my list ends up empty at the end of the loop.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list_of_lists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();          
    for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < 2; y++) {                
            list.add(x);
            list.add(y);                
            list_of_lists.add((ArrayList<Integer>) list);
            System.out.println(list_of_lists);
            list.clear();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list_of_lists);
```

**But, in console the result is:**

```
[[0, 0]]
[[0, 1], [0, 1]]
[[1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0]]
[[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]]
[[2, 0], [2, 0], [2, 0], [2, 0], [2, 0]]
[[2, 1], [2, 1], [2, 1], [2, 1], [2, 1], [2, 1]]
[[3, 0], [3, 0], [3, 0], [3, 0], [3, 0], [3, 0], [3, 0]]
[[3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1]]
[[4, 0], [4, 0], [4, 0], [4, 0], [4, 0], [4, 0], [4, 0], [4, 0], [4, 0]]
[[4, 1], [4, 1], [4, 1], [4, 1], [4, 1], [4, 1], [4, 1], [4, 1], [4, 1], [4, 1]]
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

**Why, the final is a empy list insteed of :**

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 1], [3, 0], [3, 1], [4, 0], [4, 1]]
```

**It's with each other instead of two separate lists. My code was linking one list to another**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for being the last list empty is that **Java stores everything in the form of references** i.e in the form of memory address and manipulates them in the same way.

Hence ,the ArrayList object list is also a reference.
So

1) Everytime the inner loop is run a reference to `list` object is added to the ArrayList `list_of_lists`.

2) Hence each time the list is manipulated the `list_of_lists` stores the value of list as many times as the inner loop is run i.e. the list is added to it.

Hence Each time `System.out.println(list_of_lists)` is called

1) it prints `list` same no of times it is added to `list_of_lists`.

2) the list is cleared with `list.clear()` after that which makes all the references to `list` empty.

You can also check this code to get list_of_lists at each iteration to get a clear picture of what is happening.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list_of_lists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();          
for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < 2; y++) {                
        list.add(x);
        list.add(y);                
        list_of_lists.add((ArrayList<Integer>) list);
        System.out.println(list_of_lists);
        list.clear();
    }
    System.out.println(list_of_lists); //composes of empty lists 
                                        //the same of times list is added to it
}
System.out.println(list_of_lists);
```

**Solution:*

To create a List of Lists you have to allocate memory each time new list is added to `list_of_lists`:

```
  ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list_of_lists = new 
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        List<Integer> list;        
        for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < 2; y++) {  
                list = new ArrayList<>();              
                list.add(x);
                list.add(y);                
                list_of_lists.add((ArrayList<Integer>) list);
                System.out.println(list_of_lists);
                // list.clear();
            }
         }
          System.out.println(list_of_lists);
        }
```

Comment: WOW. 
Thanks brow! u saved me!

Answer (score 1):

It's because all your sublists points to the same instance. You should create new instance for each pair of numbers instead of reusing `list`. Check the code below

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list_of_lists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    List<Integer> list;
    for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
            list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            list.add(x);
            list.add(y);
            list_of_lists.add((ArrayList<Integer>) list);
            System.out.println(list_of_lists);
            //list.clear();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list_of_lists);
```

The output will be

```
[[0, 0]]
[[0, 0], [0, 1]]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0]]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0]]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 1]]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 1], [3, 0]]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 1], [3, 0], [3, 1]]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 1], [3, 0], [3, 1], [4, 0]]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 1], [3, 0], [3, 1], [4, 0], [4, 1]]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 1], [3, 0], [3, 1], [4, 0], [4, 1]]
```